# Adding values to non zero elements in a Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in which I want to increment all the values of non-zero elements by one. However, I cannot figure it out. Is there a way to do it using standard packages in python? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How many dimensions you matrix have?

Comment: Hi, I am using a 1Mx1.5M dimensional matrix. I tried using a numpy matrix, but it works on smaller dimensions. This is too big for my system, I am using 16GB of RAM right now. So I just wanted to add values to all the non zero elements in a sparse matrix.

Comment: Have you tried the solution that I wrote in my answer below?

Comment: Related: [Avoid implicit conversion to matrix in numpy operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548269/3002584), as well as: [Why does `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` broadcast multiplication but not subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74637337/3002584)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot comment on it's performance but you can do (Scipy 1.1.0);

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> a = csr_matrix([[0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
>>> print(a)
(0, 1)        2
(1, 0)        1
>>> a[a.nonzero()] = a[a.nonzero()] + 1
>>> print(a)
(0, 1)        3
(1, 0)        2
```

Comment: This gives error- ```NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported```

Comment: @atinjanki Hi, thanks for the feedback. It may related to scipy version, I've updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix have 2 dimensions, you can do the following:

```
sparse_matrix = [[element if element==0 else element+1 for element in row ]for row in sparse_matrix]
```

It will iterate over every element of your matrix and return the element without any change if it is equals to zero, else it add 1 to the element and return it.

More about conditionals in list comprehension in [the answer for this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)n.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `numpy` which has efficient functions for dealing with n-dimensional arrays. What you need is:

**`array[array>0] += 1`**

where `array` is the numpy array of your matrix. Example here:
   `

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = [[2,0,0,0,7],[0,0,0,4,0]]
array = np.array(my_matrix);
print("Matrix before incrementing values: \n", array)
array[array>0] += 1
print("Matrix after incrementing values: \n", array)`
```

Outputs:

```
Matrix before incrementing values: 
 [[2 0 0 0 7]
 [0 0 0 4 0]]
Matrix after incrementing values: 
 [[3 0 0 0 8]
 [0 0 0 5 0]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I have tried this approach before & it works well for matrices having a reasonable dimension. In my case I am am using a [1Mx1.5M] dimensional matrix. M is a million here. So I am not being able to convert this sparse matrix to a numpy array as it is giving me a memory error. I am having 16 GB of RAM, and there's no way I can remove the features or delete some rows. So the ideal solution will be a sparse matrix. So as a correction to my question, I wanted to ask specifically about adding values to non zero elements in a sparse matrix and not a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `scipy` sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse`) is:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
my_matrix = [[2,0,0,0,7],[0,0,0,4,0]]
my_matrix = sp.csc_matrix(my_matrix)
my_matrix.data += 1
my_matrix.todense()
```

Returns:

```
[[3, 0, 0, 0, 8], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0]]
```